# Fire ActionEvent first

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield

I have extended JTextField. There are multiple ActionListeners attached to my class, but I need one in particular to always fire first. Is there a way to ensure that a particular ActionEvent always first first?

Note that I do have a reference to my ActionListener. I am assuming I need to override a method, but I am not sure which one that is.

Comment: `but I need one in particular to always fire first.` - Why? Sound like a bad design. Give us the real requirement, not your attempted solution, and we may be able to suggest a better approach.

Comment: See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: My JTextField displays a formatted money string. When the user clicks the textbox, it switches to its real value. For example, the text box displays $1.00, but when the user clicks on it to edit it, it displays 1.0.

Comment: What does an ActionListener have to do with the problem? A mouseClick just gives the component focus. So what is your requirement? You want the formatting to be constant and change dynamically as a character is typed/removed from the text field? If so then you should probably be using a [Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter). Or, usually formatting is done when the component loses focus, in which case you should be able to use a JFormattedTextField.

Comment: Yes, I use the mouse listener and focus listeners to switch back and forth between the formatted text and the non formatted text. The problem comes into play when the user presses enter on the text field. I need to do some processing on the value that they entered. This needs to happen before other action listners do their thing.

Comment: See my edit. Still not sure about your approach.

Answer (score 3):

Try to override fireActionPerformed from JTextField. Add custom ActionListener in new class and call him before call super.fireActionPerformed()

Ps: sorry for bad english.

**Edit:**

```
public class CustomTextField extends JTextField {
    private List<ActionListener> listeners;

    public synchronized void addPriorityActionListener(ActionListener l) {
        if(l == null) {
            return;
        }

        if(listeners == null) {
            listeners = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        listeners.add(l);
    }

    public synchronized void removePriorityActionListener(ActionListener l) {
        if(l == null || listeners == null) {
            return;
        }

        listeners.remove(l);
    }

    protected void firePriorityActionPerformed() {
        if(listeners == null) {
            return;
        }

        ActionEvent event = new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, getText());

        for(ActionListener listener: listeners) {
            listener.actionPerformed(event);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void fireActionPerformed() {
        firePriorityActionPerformed();
        super.fireActionPerformed();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to ensure that a particular ActionEvent always first first?

The Java spec does not guarantee the order in which events are fired.

However, I believe the default implementation is that the last ActionListener added to a component is first first.

Edit:

> I use the mouse listener

Why are you using a MouseListener? What happens when the user tabs to/from the field? Don't assume mouse usage. A FocusListener will handle either keyboard or mouse activity in this case.

> The problem comes into play when the user presses enter on the text field.

What happens if the user doesn't press enter and they just tab to the next field? That's what I would do.

> This needs to happen before other action listners do their thing.

What other ActionListeners? A tgext field would only have a single listener.

Anyway do maybe answer your question you can effectively change the order of execution by using SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...) to place your code on the end of the Event Dispatch Thread so it executes after all other events:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            // add your code here
        }
    });
}
```

Again, any solution that depends on the order of events is not a good solution. The order of event could be different on different platforms.